# Why won't the root processes sort when I attempt sorting the users based on the number of processes running?

Tags: text-processing, sort, ps

Currently I am working in a remote environment where I would like to sort the number of users using up the most processes with the ps command.The only problem is; with my current command; the root user is not displayed which should be displayed. The first output is what I'm looking for, the latter is what I currently receive.

```
157 root
 12 apache
 11 brun1992
  4 bb
  2 postfix
  2 hart4492
  2 68
  1 USER
  1 sshd
  1 rpcuser
```

MY COMMAND:

```
 ps -eo user=|sort|uniq -c | head -n 10 | sort -r $1
         9 apache
         6 au6620
         5 ande7941
         4 cwen4344
         4 bb
         3 dagg9715
         2 evan8561
         2 brun1992
         2 alki2221
         1 dbus
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
ps -eo user|sort|uniq -c|sort -gr
```

> sort -gr is the key to it.
>
> > -g :   Sort numerically.

Comment: That works like my command, but I still do not see the root, I feel like in my command it is only skipping the first line or something

Comment: @BrandonW000 does "ps -eo user" shows root user ?

Comment: I only get apache at the top, but root is running the most processes right?

Comment: @BrandonW000 try with this link http://serverfault.com/questions/706032/ps-aux-shows-only-processes-of-the-current-user
btw which OS are you using?

Comment: @Rackesh.N Ubuntu

Comment: Nevermind your solution is correct, thank you

Comment: @BrandonW000 No problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have the head before the sort. I think you are trying to find the top ten used usernames. First, as @rakesh-n says, you need to sort numerically.

But the problem is you get a list out of uniq that is sorted by username and then you take the top ten and only after that you sort by count. Have a look at your example and notice all the usernames start with a-e

> ps -eo user=|sort|uniq -c | sort -r $1 | head -n 10